# Convert a Json in a new structure

Tags: arrays, json, scala

Hello I have a web service in scala and i want that it answer with a particular data to an ajax request
So how can I convert in scala this Json:

```
 [
  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Citta": "BARI",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  },

  {
    "Quantita": 30,
    "Citta": "BARI",
    "GENERE": "Storia"
  },
  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  },

  {
    "Quantita": 6,
    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Storia"
  },
  {
    "Quantita": 8,
    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
    "GENERE": "Avventura"
  }]
```

In an array of array like this:

```
 [
['Bari','Avventura',6],
    ['Bari','Storia',30],
    ['Modugno','Avventura',6],
    ['Modugno','Giallo',6],
    ['Modugno','Storia',6],
    ['Avventura','Bari',6],
    ['Avventura','Modugno',6],
    ['Storia','Bari',30],
    ['Storia','Modugno',6]
]
```

Please help me :)

Comment: I don't know how can make it. I need some help or solution

Comment: What JSON library?

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please explain better

Comment: On this website, it is customary to ask the users to make a minimal effort and to show some of the code that they have written. For instance: choose one of the libraries from http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/, write some code and let us know exactly what does not work

Comment: @Mozzer So is your desired result a json array of json arrays or a scala array of scala arrays? In other words: do you want to perform a json transformation or a mapping from json to scala structures? That's not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

## Json4s library

Looks like you are new to Stackoverflow. Here is the example to start.

Create a sbt project and in the `build.sbt`

`build.sbt`

```
name := "foobar"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.4.2")
```

`Main.scala` in src folder

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

object Main {

  def convert(jsonString: String): String = {
    val parsedJson = parse(jsonString)
    parsedJson.children.map {
      case JObject(list) =>
        val map = list.toMap
        val JString(citta) = map("Citta")
        val JString(genere) = map("GENERE")
        val JInt(quantita) = map("Quantita")
        List(citta, genere, quantita).map(str => s"'$str'").mkString("[", ",", "]\n")
      case _ => List.empty[String]
    }.mkString("[", ",", "]")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(convert(
      """
        | [
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "BARI",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  },
        |
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 30,
        |    "Citta": "BARI",
        |    "GENERE": "Storia"
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  },
        |
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Storia"
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 8,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  }]
        |
      """.stripMargin))
  }
}
```

to run the project do `sbt run` and see the output on the console.

Note: Format your output according to your requirements and also take care of camel case.

output:

```
[['BARI','Avventura','6']
,['BARI','Storia','30']
,['MODUGNO','Avventura','6']
,['MODUGNO','Storia','6']
,['MODUGNO','Avventura','8']
]
```

## Play Json

`build.sbt`

```
name := "foobar"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.5.4")
```

`Main.scala`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Main {

  case class Record(quantita: Int, citta: String, genere: String)

  object Record {
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
    implicit val recordReads: Reads[Record] = (
      (JsPath \ "Quantita").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "Citta").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "GENERE").read[String]
      )(Record.apply _)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parsedJson =
    Json.parse(
      """
        |[
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "BARI",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  },
        |
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 30,
        |    "Citta": "BARI",
        |    "GENERE": "Storia"
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  },
        |
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 6,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Storia"
        |  },
        |  {
        |    "Quantita": 8,
        |    "Citta": "MODUGNO",
        |    "GENERE": "Avventura"
        |  }]
        |
      """.stripMargin)
    parsedJson.validate[List[Record]] match {
      case JsSuccess(value, _) =>
        value.map { record =>
          s"""[${record.citta},${record.genere},${record.quantita}]\n"""
        }.mkString("[", ",", "]")
      case JsError(_) => println("")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try Tomorrow. I Can see that you use json4s library. I use play framwork. Maybe i Can make this convertion also with play...

Comment: @Mozzer Updated with Play json as well

Comment: Please, Have you got a play solution that I will try Tomorrow?

Comment: Ok i see now the update. Thank you so much i Will try everything Tomorrow. :)

Comment: I have this problem when i do this  `parsedJson.validate[List[Libro_D]]  match {  ` 



"◾No Json deserializer found for type List[Item.Libro_D]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
◾not enough arguments for method validate: (implicit rds: play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[Item.Libro_D]])play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Item.Libro_D]]. Unspecified value parameter rds.

Comment: I resolve with this `implicit val f = Json.format[Libro_D]`
But now i have a problem... when i print the parsedJson.validate[List[Libro_D]] etc. i have an empty list

Comment: @Mozzer go through play Jason documentation to understand play Json better

Comment: @Mozzer do not use format ... instead use reads. in case of format .. the json field name should match the case class data member field name. Because the json parsing is failing you are getting empty list

Comment: ok thank you... but now i have a problem... I want  ['BARI', 'Avventura', 6] and not ['BARI', 'Avventura', '6']...So i need that all "quantita" value become int. How can i make it?

Comment: Declare quantita as int in your case class